# Maria Db 10.1 User for remote access not work

Tags: mysql, mariadb

On server with MariaDB 10.1 add user with grant privileges, for access remotly not work.

Steps.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'XXXXXX'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'WWWWWWWWW' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Verify

```
SELECT * from information_schema.user_privileges where grantee like "'xxxxxxx'%";
+----------------+---------------+-------------------------+--------------+
| GRANTEE        | TABLE_CATALOG | PRIVILEGE_TYPE          | IS_GRANTABLE |
+----------------+---------------+-------------------------+--------------+
| 'xxxxxxx'@'%' | def           | SELECT                  | YES          |
| 'xxxxxxx'@'%' | def           | INSERT                  | YES          |
| 'xxxxxxx'@'%' | def           | UPDATE                  | YES          |
| 'xxxxxxx'@'%' | def           | DELETE                  | YES          |
| 'xxxxxxx'@'%' | def           | CREATE                  | YES          |
| 'xxxxxxx'@'%' | def           | DROP                    | YES          |
| 'xxxxxxx'@'%' | def           | RELOAD                  | YES          |
| 'xxxxxxx'@'%' | def           | SHUTDOWN                | YES          |
| 'xxxxxxx'@'%' | def           | PROCESS                 | YES          |
| 'xxxxxxx'@'%' | def           | FILE                    | YES          |
| 'xxxxxxx'@'%' | def           | REFERENCES              | YES          |
| 'xxxxxxx'@'%' | def           | INDEX                   | YES          |
| 'xxxxxxx'@'%' | def           | ALTER                   | YES          |
| 'xxxxxxx'@'%' | def           | SHOW DATABASES          | YES          |
| 'xxxxxxx'@'%' | def           | SUPER                   | YES          |
| 'xxxxxxx'@'%' | def           | CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES | YES          |
| 'xxxxxxx'@'%' | def           | LOCK TABLES             | YES          |
| 'xxxxxxx'@'%' | def           | EXECUTE                 | YES          |
| 'xxxxxxx'@'%' | def           | REPLICATION SLAVE       | YES          |
| 'xxxxxxx'@'%' | def           | REPLICATION CLIENT      | YES          |
| 'xxxxxxx'@'%' | def           | CREATE VIEW             | YES          |
| 'xxxxxxx'@'%' | def           | SHOW VIEW               | YES          |
| 'xxxxxxx'@'%' | def           | CREATE ROUTINE          | YES          |
| 'xxxxxxx'@'%' | def           | ALTER ROUTINE           | YES          |
| 'xxxxxxx'@'%' | def           | CREATE USER             | YES          |
| 'xxxxxxx'@'%' | def           | EVENT                   | YES          |
| 'xxxxxxx'@'%' | def           | TRIGGER                 | YES          |
| 'xxxxxxx'@'%' | def           | CREATE TABLESPACE       | YES          |
+----------------+---------------+-------------------------+--------------+
28 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

But when try access form other host

```
mysql -u xxxxxx -h 178.33.XXX.XXX -p
Enter password:
ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host '88.14.189.149' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server
```

also try

```
telnet 178.33.XXX.XXX 3306
Trying 178.33.XXX.XXX...
Connected to kvm401.tamainut.net.
Escape character is '^]'.
HHost '88.14.189.149' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB serverConnection closed by foreign host.
```

VErification password on new format

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select User,Host,password from mysql.user where user LIKE '%xxxxx%' ;
+----------------+--------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| User           | Host               | password                                  |
+----------------+--------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| setdart_xxxxx | domain.tld          | *E6B7483F265D61567967300758B7872E03110534 |
| setdart_xxxxx | XX.XXX.XXX.XX       | *E6B7483F265D61567967300758B7872E03110534 |
| setdart_xxxxx | kvm401.domain.tld   | *E6B7483F265D61567967300758B7872E03110534 |
| setdart_xxxxx | XX.XXX.XXX.XX       | *E6B7483F265D61567967300758B7872E03110534 |
| setdart_xxxxx | XX.XXX.XXX.XX       | *E6B7483F265D61567967300758B7872E03110534 |
| setdart_xxxxx | XX.XXX.XXX.XX       | *E6B7483F265D61567967300758B7872E03110534 |
| setdart_xxxxx | XX.XXX.XXX.XX       | *E6B7483F265D61567967300758B7872E03110534 |
| setdart_xxxxx | XX.XXX.XXX.XX       | *E6B7483F265D61567967300758B7872E03110534 |
| setdart_xxxxx | XX.XXX.XXX.XX7      | *E6B7483F265D61567967300758B7872E03110534 |
| setdart_xxxxx | XX.XXX.XXX.XX       | *E6B7483F265D61567967300758B7872E03110534 |
| setdart_xxxxx | mysql.domain.tld    | *E6B7483F265D61567967300758B7872E03110534 |
| setdart_xxxxx | XX.XXX.XXX.XX       | *E6B7483F265D61567967300758B7872E03110534 |
| setdart_xxxxx | localhost           | *E6B7483F265D61567967300758B7872E03110534 |
+----------------+--------------------+-------------------------------------------+
13 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Why not work?

Comment: That particular GRANT is opening the door to a hacker.

Comment: It's grant for specifique Ip, no for all ip. Security is not paranoic status.

Answer (score 0):

After checking source of [sql_acl.cc](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/11c85e1d9fab12ed6da00d562084598b633664a3/sql/sql_acl.cc#L2649) only thing which comes to mind is to

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
FLUSH HOSTS;
```

This may help for case when connecting client's IP had many ACL errors before.

Answer (score -2):

You have also to configure your server for remote connections (my.conf). The standard configuration skips networking and so you can only connect via localhost. Otherwise you would also get another exception like access denied if there is a user privilege problem. If you do not know where you will find your configuration file, then have a look at [mariadb](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/configuring-mariadb-for-remote-client-access/), because it is depending on your OS.

You have to commented out (prefaced with hash (#) characters) the following lines:

```
    [mysqld]
    ...
    #skip-networking
    ...
    #bind-address = <some ip-address>
```

like that. okay you could also set the bind address to 0.0.0.0 if you have to use multiple interfaces, but that is also the standard advice at mariadb. After that you have to restart your server and it will work.

Comment: This makes no sense. If server is not configured to remote access, it will not give error message about denied access, because server will not listen at remote address at all.

Comment: okay you are right. Then I was maybe too fast and have to accept the downvotes :(

Comment: there are unfortunately many reasons for that error. So normally it sounds like you did not flush the privileges,but we can see that you did. There can be something wrong in your mysql.user table or it could e.g. also that a wrong glibc is linked.If nothing will help,try also to reset all privileges and create them again.But look first at the mysql.user table how your root user is configured (only local, auth_plugin)

`shell>   mysql --no-defaults -h127.0.0.1 -uroot -p
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
TRUNCATE mysql.user;
GRANT ALL ON *.* to root@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`